# Onmousehover in more than one section

Tags: javascript

I'm trying use js onmousehover to hover over an image and in a seperate fixed location tell me the name of said image. I have successfully done this but I can only get it to work on the first element when I have about six that I need to do. here is a sample of my code:

```
function getElementsById(ids) {
    var idList = ids.split(" ");
    var results = [], item;
    for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
        item = document.getElementById(idList[i]);
        if (item) {
            results.push(item);
        }
    }
    return(results);
}

function hover(description) {
    console.log(description);
    document.getElementsById('content content1').innerHTML = description;
}
```

and to call it I've been using this:

```
<div class="product-description-box">
    <p>
      <div class="colorHeading">colors available: <span class="selectedColor" id="content"></span></div>
      <div class="prodColors"></div> 
    </p>
</div>
```

I am using different ids for each section. Js is for sure not my strong suit so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that you can't use native block elements like `div` inside paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faster way of doing it is to pull your elements collection and then convert it into an array:

Like so:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("box"))
    .forEach(function(element) {element.addEventListener("mouseover", checkBoxColor);});
```

This calls slice on the collection of HTML elements returned by getElementsByClassName in order to convert it into an Array. After that I run the forEach method to add the event listener to each HTML element.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0saLvq2q/

In your case if you need to return multiple elements by many different ID's you can use querySelectorAll() to pull the elements instead of getElementsByClassName().

Answer (score 0):

'ids' isn't automatically a list. What you want to use is the [Arguments Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp).

```
function getElementsById() {
var i, results = [], item;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    item = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
    if (item) {
        results.push(item);
    }
}
return(results);
```